# Finding x-axis-intercept of a parametric equation and slope

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, parametrization, slope

let $x = t^2$ and $y = t^3-3t$

now the equation for the slope is:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3t^2-3}{2t} = 0$$

now at the point (0,0) is the first intercept with the x-axis with slope $\infty$ what is the slope at the second intercept and how to find the second intercept?

Comment: The x-intercept is where $x = t^2 = 0$.  The y-intercepts are where $y = t^3 - 3t = 0$.  Thus for $t = 0$, $x=y=0$ is both an x- and a y-intercept.  There are two other y-intercepts, however.  Once you solve for the value of $t$ for these y-intercepts, you may substitute them into your slope formula.

Comment: @JimFerry what's the other x intercept?

Comment: The $x$ intercepts are where $y=0$ so $t \in \{-\sqrt 3 , 0, \sqrt3 \}$, the other intercept is $(3, 0)$ having slope equal to $\sqrt 3$

Comment: There is only one x-intercept because $t^2 = 0$ has only one solution.  Whoops!  Never mind:  I was mixing up x- and y-intercepts.